# JS: remodeling a class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reformulate my class so that I can do something like :

```
 let myPlayer = new NewPlayer().init;

 let player = myPlayer('id', myConfigObj, {});
```

I want to be able to init it like that but I can't see how to do it. Is it possible to restructure it like that so I can use it like that?

---

```
class NewPlayer {
  constructor() {
    this.player = {};
  }

  init() {
    {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store a reference to the init function in `myPlayer`, but the `this` of that function is not bound to the instance. It's actually `undefined`.

Here is my suggested fix:

```js
import videojs from 'video.js';

class NewPlayer {
  constructor() {
    this.player = {};
  }

  get init() {
    return this._init.bind(this)
  }

  _init(videoPlayerID, videoJSConfig, ivsTech) {
    if (ivsTech) {
      ivsTech(videojs);
    };
    videoJSConfig.techOrder = ['AmazonIVS'];
    this.player = videojs(videoPlayerID, videoJSConfig);
    return this.player;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how would that be used then to init in that style since there's a getter

Comment: The same way as you did. The getter binds the context to the function, so it'll work the same but resolve the issue.

Comment: It's compatible with the code you posted as an example on how you would like to be able to use it. Now `init` returns a reference to the same function, but where `this` of that function is correctly  bound to your class instance.